# no form request from node

Tags: html, node.js, forms, web

I am trying to submit my form but its not showing anything
this is my file directory structure

[image]

when clicking on submit button nothing changes.
it show no changes.

```html
<form id="contactForm" method="post" action="/">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3>Book a table</h3>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="input_date" class="datepicker picker__input form-control" name="date" type="text" value="" equired data-error="Please enter Date">
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="input_time" class="time form-control picker__input" name="time" required data-error="Please enter time">
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="custom-select d-block form-control" id="person" name="person" required data-error="Please select Person">
            <option disabled selected>Select Person*</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
          </select>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3>Contact Details</h3>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" required data-error="Please enter your name">
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" required data-error="Please enter your email">
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Your Numbar" id="phone" class="form-control" name="phone" required data-error="Please enter your Numbar">
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="submit-button text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-common" id="submit" type="submit">Book Table</button>
        <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**this is index.js file code**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get("/" , function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
});
app.get("/reservation" , function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/reservation.html");
});

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    console.log("request send");
    console.log(req.body);
  });
```

The get request are working proper but post request is not working

I try to change the method of the form but stil its not working

Answer (score 0):

The `post` handler never returns a response. Adding one should fix things:

```js
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  console.log("request send");
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("done"); // Here!
});
```